# Delete files with different extensions

Tags: windows, powershell, batch, batch-file

i have the following problem:

the software with which I read out my defective hard drive gave me all files with duplicates sometimes up to 15 times. One file with its duplicates looks and are named like this:

FirstFile
FirstFile0
FirstFile1
FirstFile2
FirstFile3
FirstFile4
SecondFile
SecondFile0
SecondFile1
(File and File0 are sometimes missing, sometimes starts with File2, like:
ThirdFile2
ThirdFile3
ThirdFile4
ThirdFile5
etc.
This is how all files are presented.

I came up with the following:

First step: Sort by name in one folder (as seen in the example)
Second step: Remove the next files as long (extension=NoNumber OR numberAfter<numberBefore)

I wanted to make something out of the templates for example with batch scripts or powershell scripts but unfortunately I don't understand enough of the languages :( I need help to solve this problem, unfortunately I don't know how. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do the files have any extension??? If so Does it vary? `file0.txt`, `file1.txt`?

Answer (score 3):

These may not be duplicates.

These kind of recovery programs may return contiguous sectors of the files.
A file which is allocated over several non-contiguous chains of sectors may
come out as several files, each containing only a part.

On the other hand, the program may recover old and deleted versions of the files.
So the files may be complete, but there is no guarantee that `FirstFile`
is the real file or `FirstFile1`.

You must examine each and every fragment.

If this is too hard,
I suggest to try other recovery programs which might do better.
[Minitool](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html)
is one of the best, although the free version has limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are wanting to delete duplicaates as requested, you could use PowerShell to delete all files that have a numerical suffix:

```
Get-ChildItem -FIle | Where BaseName -match '\d+$' | Remove-Item
```